# Error installing ruby file magic on OSX

Tags: ruby, macos

```
Fetching ruby-filemagic 0.7.2
Installing ruby-filemagic 0.7.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/quantum/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/ruby-filemagic-0.7.2/ext/filemagic
/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180207-53723-1uirx0.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lgnurx... no
checking for magic_open() in -lmagic... no
*** ERROR: missing required library to compile this module
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

have_library: checking for -lgnurx... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin17 -I/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I. -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib     -lruby.2.4.2  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lobjc "
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib'
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin17 -I/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I. -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib     -lruby.2.4.2 -lgnurx  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lobjc "
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgnurx
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: 
14: int t(void) { ; return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for magic_open() in -lmagic... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin17 -I/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I. -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib     -lruby.2.4.2 -lmagic  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lobjc "
conftest.c:13:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'magic_open'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))magic_open; return !p; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))magic_open; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin17 -I/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I. -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/quantum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib     -lruby.2.4.2 -lmagic  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lobjc "
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib'
ld: library not found for -lmagic
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void magic_open();
14: int t(void) { magic_open(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

It looks like the `magic_open` is failing? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

AAA,
found the solution which helped me, spent like almost two days on it, so if it would save someones time posting here.

`brew install libmagic`

and then

`env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install -v 0.7.1 ruby-filemagic -- --with-magic-include=/usr/local/include --with-magic-lib=/usr/local/lib/`

**make sure** though that you are installing required version in `gem install -v 0.7.1 ruby-filemagic`

Answer (score 0):

`sudo brew install libmagic` fixed that for me

Comment: still getting this
`ld: library not found for -lgnurx
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
looks like `magic_open` is just a consequence

Comment: `sudo` is no longer supported by Homebrew